# Getting an interfaces `valid_lft` programmatically

Tags: kernel, network-interface, dhcp, prometheus-exporter

iproute2 can give back an interface's `valid_lft` which corresponds to the dhcp lease time left. See a truncated example output hereafter:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  ...
2: enp0s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
   ...
       valid_lft 82933sec preferred_lft 82933sec
   ...
```

I'd like to get this from preferably Golang without actually calling `ip address`. Though I realise ip route has a json output, I still much prefer to interact with, for example:

- a library which allows me access to this counter
- a path in /sys or /proc which provides access to this counter
- something else?

The goal is to expose the valid_lft counter as a metric which can be scraped by something like Prometheus. I'm amazed this is not available yet.

Comment: Well the question is to know where and how you can interface with Linux to get this data. But if that still makes it a better fit for SO, I'll ask to move it

Comment: Sorry, finally I'm not really sure (so I removed the comment).

Comment: I can just say that the canonical way is to use netlink(7) / rtnetlink(7) and this indeed is best served with a library (eg in C: http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/)

Comment: and https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/group__rtaddr.html